# Can't connect to Amazon RDS with MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to Amazon RDS with MySQL workbench, but I keep running into this error:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'admin' from your host to
>   server at database-2.cv15axugkvps.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306:
>   Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   'database-2.cv15axugkvps.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (60)
>
> Please: 1 Check that MySQL is running on the server
>   database-2.cv15axugkvps.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com
>
> 2 Check that MySQL is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default,
>   but this can be changed)
>
> 3 Check the admin has rights to connect to
>   database-2.cv15axugkvps.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com from your address
>   (MySQL rights define what clients can connect to the server and from
>   which machines)
>
> 4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the
>   correct password for
>   database-2.cv15axugkvps.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com connecting from
>   the host address you're connecting from

I know my hostname, port, username, and password are all right. I even created a second database with a new username and password just to be sure I didn't forget the originals.

It looks like this person [had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995414/connecting-to-mysql-on-aws-via-query-browser-while-outside-the-u-s?rq=1). They commented:

> Okay, I take the blame for this one. I thought port 3306 was open for
>   everywhere, but I had to assign it my IP address to allow traffic.I
>   had to get my IP address (www.whatsmyip.org) and then add that as a
>   3306 port in my security group. If your IP is 12.34.56.78, choose
>   "MySQL" from the "Create a New Rule" dropdown menu in you Security
>   Group's "Inbound" tab. Then add 12.34.56.78/32 as the Source, click
>   "Add Rule" then click "Apply Rule Changes"

I tried that but had the same problem.

Comment: Is your rds in public or private subnet?

Comment: You got it --- I made it public, and then it started working :)

Comment: Good to hear. I added answer for future reference then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was that the db instance was `private`. Changing it to `public` solved the problem.